# Tool to reteach Algebra?

Tags: self-learning, learning

I was never a very good math student and over the years, I simply forgot a lot of math. But sometimes it annoys me to no end, because I work in a mathematically related field (applied statistics) and feel like an illiterate must feel when visiting a book club.

I would really like to improve my math skills (particularly) Algebra, but I have found few good books and I would like to have som websites or, even better, offline math trainers for the computer.

The reason for using a program is simple that I commute two hours per day and using a laptop / tablet in a train is easier than juggling books and a textblock.

Comment: What kind of algebra?

Comment: I would like to start with nasic algebra, e.g. factorization.

Comment: You might like Khan Academy.

Comment: @littleO thank you, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Then you just want to pick up  a gcse/ A level core maths textbook, and keep going over examples, with things like factorisation, theres not much theory so it really is practice makes perfect.

Comment: As somebody from germany, could you kindly explain what gcse means? Our math books are utter rubbish, gemran math teachers love thorwing formulas at us, but are utterly rubbish at explaining them.

Comment: Search for either edexcel or AQA gcse or A level textbooks, (those are specific exam board textbooks), and I think gcse is for like the equivalent of 16 year old education. (Basically I don't know what secondary school is called in Germany)